# Removing spaces from strings over a certain length

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a column in my SQL Server database which determines the folder structure of a group of files. So for example the column would display the following:

```
\(folder 1)\(folder 2)\(folder3)\
\(folder 1)\(folder 2)\(folder3)\(folder 4)
\(folder 1)\(folder 2)\
```

The problem is that a single folder name must not be over 50 characters long. If it is, I'd like to remove all the spaces from that folder (but only for that folder).

So if in the first example folders 1 and 3 were under 50 characters long but folder 2 was over 50 characters long then folders 1 and 3 would remain the same and folder 2 would have spaces removed.

That's my priority at the moment but if possible, I'd like to remove '-' and '_' but only in cases where removing spaces isn't enough to lower the character count to the 50 limit.

Is there an easy way of doing this without using multiple used of `SUBSTRING`, `CHARINDEX` and `CASE`?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: No. There are no easy ways. You have to do the work. I recommend you reading how to write T-SQL statements.

Comment: Are the folder paths stored in a single VARCHAR or does your table have every folder name in a separate row?

Comment: Hello Tomalak, each row displays a folder path, so some rows can have up to about 10 folder names.

Comment: When you remove spaces, you are not pointing to the correct folder anymore. Is that a problem?

Comment: This means a lot of work if you want to do it in T-SQL. You need to split each path at the backslash into a variable number of parts, look at each part, apply your replacement logic, build the path from the parts, update the row. This can't be done easily in an SQL statement (it's technically possible, but neither pretty nor fast), you will be a lot better off doing that outside of SQL Server in a programming language that is better suited for this kind of work. (Maybe your application should be doing this before inserting the values in the first place.)

Comment: What is the size of that column? If it's a varchar(50), then the value is already truncated. No amount of space removal will bring back the characters lost. So you may need to squeeze the values *before* inserting into the table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came up with the following piece of code, I think that should solve your problem. Ping me if you have any queries

```
 DECLARE @InputString NVARCHAR(300) = 'Hello\Hello World\He He'
 DECLARE @FolderName NVARCHAR(255)
 DECLARE @pos INT
 DECLARE @UpdatedString NVARCHAR(300) = '' 
 DECLARE @Size INT = 50

 SET @InputString = CONCAT(@InputString, '\')
 WHILE CHARINDEX('\', @InputString) > 0
 BEGIN
  SELECT @pos  = CHARINDEX('\', @InputString)  
  SELECT @FolderName = SUBSTRING(@InputString, 1, @pos-1)

  IF(LEN(@FolderName) > @Size)
  BEGIN
    SET @FolderName = REPLACE(@FolderName, ' ', '')
  END

  SET @UpdatedString = CONCAT(@UpdatedString, @FolderName, '\')

  SET @InputString = SUBSTRING(@InputString, @pos+1, LEN(@InputString)-@pos)
 END

 Set @UpdatedString = SUBSTRING(@UpdatedString, 0, LEN(@UpdatedString))

 SELECT @UpdatedString
```

I think the variable names are pretty straight forward in themselves.